# Deploying WPF with SQL Compact 4 and Entity Framework 4?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I am setting up a WPF app with Entity Framework 4, using SQL Compact 4 as the data store. I have the files and the references set up for a SQL Compact 4.0 private deployment (per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174619%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)).

However, with SQL Compact 3.5, I had to add configuration entries to the App.config file (see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/05/12/troubleshooting-problem-with-private-deployment-of-sql-server-compact-3-5sp2-entity-dll.aspx)). I can't find anything on whether similar entries are required to use SQL Compact 4 with EF4 in a desktop app.

So, here's my question: Do I have to add special entries to App.config in order to use SQL Compact 4 with EF4? If so, can you point me to an article or blog post that shows them? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in [this blog post by Erik Jensen](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html):

```
<system.data>    
    <DbProviderFactories>      
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>      
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0"    
             invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
             description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
             type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, 
             Culture=neutral, 
             PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>    
    </DbProviderFactories>  
</system.data>
```

Thanks, Erik!